# Actionscript 3 Inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

i have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("body").append('<div id="ajaxBusy" class="ajaxBusy"></div>');
</script>
```

My code works fine so far but i thought to load this javascript code inside an AS3.

Is there any possibility to make it happen? To write inline javascript code inside my flash;
I found this code but i dont know how to implement

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var someVarInAS : String = 'foo';
var someOtherVarInAS : int = 10;
var jsXML : XML = 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someVarInJS = '{$("body").append('<div id="ajaxBusy" class="ajaxBusy"></div>');}';
    var someOtherVarInJS = '{$('#login').fadeIn();}';
    <![CDATA[       
        alert( 'this comes from flash: ' + someVarInJS + ', ' + someOtherVarInJS );
    ]]>
</script>;


ExternalInterface.call( "function js_" + ( new Date().getTime() ) + "(){ " + jsXML + " }" );
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: What logic are you trying to send from flash to the page?  ExternalInterface provides a way to communicate back and forth between javascript and actionscript, but a better way of handling this would be to use ExternalInterface to call javascript functions that handle that actual javascript actions as opposed to injecting javascript directly from flash.

Comment: @MSost can you please provide me a demo code?
I mean how is it possible when i am loading my flash banner to my web page it runs an external js file to do append a div to my body of the page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to an example to show how `ExternalInterface` works

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15551758/eitest.zip

What's happening is that once the Flash object is loaded on the page, it uses

```
ExtenalInterface.call();
```

to call a javascript function that's been registered on the page that the swf is on.  In the case of the example:

```
ExternalInterface.call('toJS', 'flash text');
```

calls the javascript function `toJS` and sends one argument, a string `"flash text"`.

The opposite direction is supported as well.  Calling a function on the flash object and passing in arguments will send them to flash.  You register ExternalInterface callbacks with:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback(callback_name, flash_function_to_call);
```

In the example, we register in flash a callback:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("fromJS", this.fromJS);
```

that listens for an event from javascript called `fromJS` and calls an internal function `fromJS`.  For the example, I've added a textbox on the stage to visualize the data coming in from javascript.

Please let me know if this answers your question or if you need more explanation.

Edit:

If you must inject javascript, you can pass in a function that does the injection as the first parameter of `ExternalInterface.call`:

```
var inject:String = "function(){var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], testNode = document.createElement('div'); testNode.innerHTML = 'This is a test'; body.appendChild(testNode);}";
ExternalInterface.call(inject);
```

But I'd recommend against it.  Keeping languages separate will lead to more concise and easier to debug code.

Comment: it works great @Msot! I have one more wuestion please.. how is it possible to run a javascript code inside AS3? I mean is it possible to append a div to my <body> without load external files?

Comment: @IreneT. You can pass a javascript function defined in an AS3 string as the first argument to ExternalInterface.call("function(){var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); document.appendChild(newDiv);}", null); I believe, this way you could dynamically build the javascript function using AS3

Comment: @shaunhusain and if it works i want only to give an id name to this div

Comment: Ah the joy of writing code that writes code that builds a DOM. This page should help http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml you can setAttribute on the newDiv after you create it with newDiv.setAttribute("id", "mycustomid"); basically at this point it's just an exercise in javascript.  Best of luck and happy hacking.